# how to convert objects to an array of arrays in php?

Tags: php, jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I have a jQuery post that returns some objects.

So, I have a DB query result that I do `json_encode($result)` and then I send it as a response in the `success` function inside the jQuery post.

If I console.log the response I see multiple objects. What I want is to send the response as an array of arrays.

In PHP

```
json_encode($results)
```

In javascript:

```
success: function(json) {
  console.log(json);
}
```

In console log:

```
[>Object , >Object , >Object]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$results` in php is an array of objects or of associative arrays.  Make it an array of numerically-indexed arrays before you send with casting:

```
// ASSUMING each $result object does not have its own nested arrays
foreach ($results as &$result) {
    $result = array_values((array) $result);
}
```

Note you will lose the ability to get items by column name.

But please step back and think about where your $result comes from.

If you are using mysql driver, consider doing this when building your result:

```
$results = array();
// Note we use MYSQL_NUM option, so $row looks like array('col1value', 'col2value')
while (FALSE !== ($row = mysql_result_array($resource, MYSQL_NUM))) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

json_encode($results);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript with JQuery:

> jQuery.makeArray();

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/

Answer (score 0):

In php, casting:

> $aArray = (array) $oObject;

Answer (score 0):

json encode will encode a string as a json OBJECT which in javascript is an object. in javascript an array is simply an object with special helper functions.  there shouldn't be a need to create an array from the object as you can manipulate an object as easily as you can manipulate an array.